# Где учить решать задачи?

Tags: python

Подскажите пожалуйста, если не сложно, где можно бесплатно нормально научиться решать задачи на python

Comment: Вы пришли в то место, где учатся решать задачи бесплатно.

Comment: Скорее всего, ответы на этот вопрос будут основаны на мнениях, а не на фактах и цитатах. Необходимо переформулировать его так, чтобы на него можно было дать объективный ответ.

Answer (score 2):

https://projecteuler.net/

[checkio.org/](http://checkio.org/)

https://www.codewars.com/

https://www.e-olymp.com/ru/

И это лишь немногие из ресурсов с задачами по программированию, в частности на Python.